# Google Android supported tags and atttributes

Tags: android

I am a newbie of android developer, how can I find the reference of all default tags and attributes supported by android plantform in the layout resource file?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a link of the available resource tags for Android at the developers website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#layoutresources